# How to output children product categories on parent product category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the children product categories to display on the parent product category page. The below code I have used works however it outputs all product categories not the children of the current product category I'm on.

Also I am struggling to get the category description to output a trimmed version of the text.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
<?php
            
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'hide_empty=0' );
if ( ! empty( $product_categories ) && ! is_wp_error( $product_categories ) ) {
    foreach ( $product_categories as $category ) {
        
        $cat_page_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $category ) );
        
echo '<div class="blog-archive-single" onclick="location.href='. $cat_page_link .';">';
    echo '<a href="'. $cat_page_link .'">';
        echo '<div class="blog-archive-single-image">';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("full");
                echo '</p>';
            } else {
                echo'<p><img src="/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder.png"/></p>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="blog-archive-single-content">';
            echo '<div class="single-tile-heading small-heading">';
                echo '<h3 class="title">';
                    echo esc_html( $category->name );
                echo '</h3>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="blog-archive-content">';
                echo '<p>'. wp_trim_words( category_description($category_id), 20, '...' ) .'</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="blog-archive-button">';
                echo '<div class="blog-archive-button-inner">';
                    echo '<span class="read-more-button">View Details</span>';
                    echo '<div class="blog-button-icon">';
                        echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';      
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
echo '</div>';      
    
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_term_children](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/) function to get child categories.

```
$main_term = get_queried_object();
$child_ids = get_term_children( $main_term->parent, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $child_ids as $child_id ) {
    if( $child_id != $main_term->term_id ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child_id, 'product_cat' );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child_id, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Check it out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/361045/get-child-product-categories-from-parent-product-category-in-woocommerce#answer-361046

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this doesn't seem to of worked. It only outputs the link of the current category I'm on and has now stopped outputting the category name and image.

Comment: @Naomi Added complete code to get child term.

Comment: Thank you for the full code, I have tried it however nothing is being pulled through.

Comment: That's unfortunate. BTW, this code is for Product Category Page where are you placing this code?